# Svelte.js component property is undefined within script tag with customElement: true

Tags: javascript, web-component, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

This might possibly be how Svelte.js works, but I'm curious if I'm doing something wrong, or if there's a workaround.

If I set compiler option `customElement: true`, properties passed to components are not available in the `<script>` tag within that component. I use webpack with svelte-loader. Here's a simple example:

```
// index.html

<my-app foo="testing svelte"></my-app>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>


// script.js (bundled into bundle.js)

import App from './App.svelte';
customElements.define('my-app', App);


// App.svelte

<script>
    export let foo;
    console.log(foo); // undefined

    $: bar = foo.toUpperCase(); // Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

    $: qux = String(foo).toUpperCase(); // No error, works
</script>

{ foo } // testing svelte - works, as expected

{ qux } // TESTING SVELTE - works, as expected
```

Also if `customElement: true` is not set, and the framework is instantiated with `const app = new App(...)` constructor, `console.log(foo)` would work, just as `$: bar = foo.toUpperCase()`.

Could anyone explain why Svelte works this way? Thanks, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With custom elements, props are not passed from the constructor, they are only set later on, on the component instance.

What I mean, is that with custom element, it's conceptually like doing this with a standard component:

```js
const app = new App({ target })
app.$set({ foo: 'bar' })
```

Not that:

```js
const app = new App({ target, props: { foo: 'bar' } })
```

That's why the value is initially (your `console.log`) undefined, but still shows as expected in the markup.

The reason for this is that the init function of a Svelte component (that is, the content of the `<script>` tag in your component) is called synchronously from the component constructor (that is, when you do `new App(...)`). However, at this point, attributes of the elements are not available (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251436/1387519)).

Either give your prop a default value or check it before using it...

```html
<script>
  // default value
  export let name = ''

  // ... or sanity check
  export let other
  $: otherName = other != null ? other + name : null
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks, totally makes sense now, that's why `String(foo).toUpperCase()` worked - by using the `String` constructor on a declared (undefined) variable, it's value is `'undefined'`, which is a string so `toUpperCase` wouldn't trigger an error, and when the component gets rendered, it already has the updated value. So the easiest solution is basically setting an empty string as a default value.